# Getting cluster error when trying to perform prediction

Tags: r

I have made a random forest model in Caret package. I called it rf_final. I have stacked my raster variables and I called it CqStack. I want to perform a prediction using clusterR() function. I used the following codes

```
cores<- detectCores()
beginCluster(n=cores*0.75)
pred.map<- clusterR(CqStack,predict,args = list(model= rf_final), progress="text")
endCluster()`
```

I keep getting the following error.

```
in clusterR(CqStack, predict, args = list(model = rf_final), progress = "text") : 
  cluster error
```

Would you help me please to solve this error problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When performing a prediction, you use a model (rf_final) and stacked rasters (CqStack). If the covariates used for making the model and the rasters in the stack are different, the prediction function cannot work. So, data confusion causes this problem.